# One-off job with hangfire

Tags: hangfire

How can I run a one-off job with hangfire?

It doesn't look that CRON syntax supports "run at startup and never again" type of thing.

I don't want to come up with a fixed CRON date (like 2019-02-28T15:12), because that wouldn't work across several environments.

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What we ended up with is a job that never runs, but can be triggered via Hangfire UI.

So something like this:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<SomeType>("name", service => service.Run(), NEVER);
```

For `NEVER` we use Hangfire's `Cron.Never()` implementation. It looks like it uses `Each 31st of February` for the cron expression. More info on [their Github](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/c23b01061860b4f5b5692e23e8f8cbdbe4681a8b/src/Hangfire.Core/Cron.cs#L221).

Comment: And what is NEVER exactly?

Comment: `Never` is the schedule for this job, so it means it will never run automatically. So the only way to start it is manually (e.g. via UI)

Comment: But what cron string is NEVER?  I have tested with string empty, string-null and an exception is throwed.

Comment: In case anyone is confused here is a full example. 

RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<SomeType>("name", service => service.Run(), Cron.Never());

Answer (score 1):

Don't use recurring job, instead, enqueue your job at application startup.

Comment: how to do this?

Comment: In your startup.cs, after hangfire is initialized, use BackgroundJob.Enqueue(...);

Comment: I've done it like this: builder.Services.AddHangfire(config =>
{   BackgroundJob.Enqueue<AppJobs>(x => x.....); });

Answer (score 1):

[BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!"));](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/calling-methods-in-background.html)
Fire's a once off job.
I would add this right after the hangfire 
[config at startup](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/)

Comment: This works only if you have a single instance of your application running, otherwise, you'll end up with one enqueued job per instance. The accepted answer is the solution that works in all scenarios.